# ScriptApp.newTrigger. Required permissions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a trigger to fetch data based on cell value automatically.
the custom formula that I create and use in a sheet (or cell) successfully fetches the data, for example :

=ListPlugins("https://example1.wpengine.com")

the function looks like this :

```
function ListPlugins(url) {
  let sheet_name = 'apps and plugins'

  var options = {
     "async": true,
     "crossDomain": true,
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       "Token" : TOKEN_HERE,
       "cache-control": "no-cache"
     }
   };
  var urlEncoded = encodeURI(url)
  let api_url = urlEncoded + "/wp-json/bd/v1/public/plugin-list/"
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url,options)
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText())

  return object;
}
```

but when I try to automate it by using the trigger, an error happens

```
​Exception: You do not have permission to call ScriptApp.newTrigger. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
```

​
and this is how my approach to automating:

```
function onOpen(e) {
 return teste()
}

function teste()
{
  var all_data = getDataFromPluginList()

  /*return all_data 
  [ { first_cell: 'A2',
    last_cell: 'I9',
    first_row: 2,
    last_row: 9,
    total_row: 8,
    url: 'https://example1.wpengine.com/' },
  { first_cell: 'A10',
    last_cell: 'I15',
    first_row: 10,
    last_row: 15,
    total_row: 6,
    url: 'https://example2.wpengine.com/' } ]

  */

  for (var i = 0; i < all_data.length; i++) {
    trigger_(all_data[i].url);
  }
}

function trigger_(url)
{
 var new_trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger(writePluginData).timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
 var trigger_id = new_trigger.getUniqueId();
 PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty(trigger_id, url);
}

function writePluginData(event) 
{

  var trig = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  let sheet_name = 'trigger_result';
  let lowest_row = lowestRow(sheet_name);
  for(var i =0; i<trig.length; i++)
  {
   if(trig[i].getUniqueId()== event.triggerUid )
   {
    var urlParam = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty(event.triggerUid);
    urlParam = urlParam.split(",");
    var url = urlParam[0];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheet_name); // change accordingly
    var data = ListPlugins(URL);

/*return listPlugins

[
    [
        "Escape Room",
        "https://example.com/",
        "Advanced Custom Fields PRO",
        "advanced-custom-fields-pro",
        "5.12.3",
        "6.0.7",
        false,
        6,
        "2023-01-30 10:57 AM"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "",
        "Classic Editor",
        "classic-editor",
        "1.6.2",
        "1.6.2",
        true,
        ""
    ],
    ...,
]
*/
    var target = "A"+ (lowest_row + 1)
    Logger.log(data);
    ss.getRange(target).setValue(data);
   }
  }
}
```

why does this error happen? is there any relation to my API security?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your error message and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, the argument of `ScriptApp.newTrigger(value)` is required to be a string type. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname) But, in your script, the function is directly used. I'm worried about whether this might be related to your current issue.

Comment: hi @Tanaike, so whenever i tried to run the automation by running "teste()" func or create a trigger to run the function, the error message appear, ahh but you're right about the argument of ScriptApp.newTrigger(value) is required to be a string type, I will fix the value first and let see the result then, thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you modified the argument of `ScriptApp.newTrigger`, can I ask you about your current situation? 1. How do you run `teste()`? 2. In your situation, the scopes are fixed by `appsscript.json`?

Comment: currently works fine with no error in the script but the data is not written at all even when  I change the `setValue()` to `setValues()` , I use `teste()` like using a formula in the cell and the trigger created and run automatically